# Manually add cookie to chrome/intellij/tomcat deployment configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, cookies, tomcat7

I'm doing a WAR deployment on a local tomcat instance to my localhost using Intellij and opening it with Chrome. Is there a way to manually set a cookie without modifying the project?

I need this because at our company we use a session cookie from an application portal for Single-Sign-On to authenticate and access application privileges/roles through our LDAP system and it's tied to our domain. I would like to manually set this session cookie while debugging without modifying the project. I was hoping maybe there was a simple addition to the run/debug config or somewhere in chrome like an extension, maybe even a JVM argument?

I have seen it's probably possible by setting up a reverse proxy or something like that, but that's probably more work than modifying the source to skip authentication.

Comment: You could add a second dummy webapp which will set a cookie and deploy this webapp together with your main one or just put it into the default `webapps` directory and make sure the option to deploy the default webapps is enabled in Tomcat run/debug configuration.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'll have to try that, thanks for the suggestion Serge

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding a cookie to chrome is pretty easy.

Open the Developer Tools quickly via the F12 key or the standard method of the kebab menu > More Tools > Developer Tools. Navigate to the Application tab, and on the left, you will see Cookies. Open Cookies and add an entry in the main part of the window. It should be persistent until you clear your cookies.

I'll still be leaving this question open as I would much rather have a solution for IntelliJ since it would likely be more configurable if/when the functionality exists does exist.